# How to do a union and specify that polygons must be greater than a certain area (e.g. 0.1 acres or greater)

Tags: arcgis-pro, union

I am doing a Union (or possibly an identity) of several polygon layers.   I want to the result to contain only polygons .05 acres or greater,  but do not want to eliminate any area.

How do I proceed?

I've tried Unioning and increasing the tolerance,   but it's iterative and time-consuming.

Comment: After Union, Eliminate will merge selected Polygons (area less than .1 ac) into an adjacent Polygon. This will not create gaps.

Comment: Is this the Eliminate tool?    What logic does it use to combine or merge into the adjacent polygons?

Comment: You can specify LENGTH, which is the longest shared Border, or greatest AREA to define how each Polygon is merged. An advanced license is needed for Eliminate.